# How to format Datatime in RDLC to display in Local Datetime format?

Tags: c#, datetime, mvvm, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have RDLC Report in which we are displaying rows with DateTime values. It Displays the date time in format HH:MM:SS tt (01:10:22 PM) .

Here i want to display in 24 Hrs format (13:10:22). I understand it can be done using Formatting in rdlc. But I want to do it based on the flag set in code behind. If flag is set to true, i have to display in 24 hrs format, else 12 hrs format.

Can any one tell me how to access a property or variable from Codebehind in RDLC ? or any other options to achieve the same..

EDIT:
 RDLC file is loaded through code in ReportViewer and displayed, so even if i add a hidden parameter in the Local Report, RDLC file doesn't know about that. So it is throwing error at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ReportParameter](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/localmodeparameters/) (i.e. *parDisplay24Hours*) and set *Field Expression* using `IIf`:

```
=IIf(Parameters!parDisplay24Hours.Value, <format DateTime values as 24h>, <format DateTime values as 12h>)
```